# How should I create the reduce if I need to loop over all the mapper values?

Tags: python, mapreduce

I have two yields from my mapper:

```
yield (destination,{'origin':origin,'count':count})
yield (origin,{'destination':destination,'count':count})
```

This gives me an output like the following:

```
('United States', {'origin': 'Romania', 'count': '1'})
('Romania', {'count': '1', 'destination': 'United States'})
('United States', {'origin': 'Ireland', 'count': '264'})
('Ireland', {'count': '264', 'destination': 'United States'})
('United States', {'origin': 'India', 'count': '69'})
('India', {'count': '69', 'destination': 'United States'})
('Egypt', {'origin': 'United States', 'count': '24'})
('United States', {'count': '24', 'destination': 'Egypt'})
('Equatorial Guinea', {'origin': 'United States', 'count': '1'})
('United States', {'count': '1', 'destination': 'Equatorial Guinea'})
('United States', {'origin': 'Singapore', 'count': '25'})
('Singapore', {'count': '25', 'destination': 'United States'})
```

Now I need to write a reducer, where I can split the above said data into two groups and iterate using two for loops. 
The idea is to find a total of all possible flights that can be made in two jumps

For example:

To get from Romania to Egypt. We take `Romania -> United States and United States -> Egypt. The total possible flights would then be 1*24`

From what I understand, I need to loop over all the values twice, and find keys where `Destination of 1 == origin of another.`

Uptill now, I think that I need to create two groups: g1(for all origin based keys) and g2(for all destination based keys)

and then iterate over each group finding such `g1.destination == g2.origin`.

Am I going in the right direction ? If so how would a function like this look in reducer ? I can't honestly seem to figure out how I should code it.